# Como instanciar uma parte de uma classe com EntityFramework trabalhar com o CRUD somente nesses dados

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Estou criando uma solução para a web no tipo SinglePageAplication (SPA) feita com AspNetCore e utilizo o Entity Framework para fazer meu CRUD no banco de dados SQL Server. Tenho a certeza que o Entity Framework me permite que eu faça a updates de somente o que mudar em uma classe então, tenho a intenção de estruturar meu frontend para que ele só envie os atributos para o servidor que mudaram, por exemplo:

**Pessoa.cs (a classe com todos os atributos)**

```
internal class Pessoa 
{
    public string primeiroNome { get; set; }
    public string segundoNome { get; set; }
    public int idade { get; set; }
    public string cpf { get; set; }
    // ... mais outros inúmeros campos
}
```

Essa classe é usada no meu `controller` para receber o CRUD vindo do frontend sendo:

`GET = SELECT | POST = INSERT | PUT = UPDATE | DELETE = DELETE`

**PessoaControler.cs (parte do controle que recebe o ajax como exemplo)**

```
internal class PessoaController 
{

    [HttpPut("/")]
    internal IActionResult Update([FromBody] Pessoa pessoa)
    {
       // ... todo o tratamento que preciso para salvar no EF 
    }

}
```

**Requisição Ajax que é feita a partir do meu frontend para a atualização (pensando em uma chamada simples utilizando jQuery como exemplo)**

```
(function(){
    // exemplo de atualização só do nome da pessoa
    var pessoa = { nome: 'teste 123' };
    $.ajax({
        method: 'put',
        url: '/',
        data: JSON.stringify(pessoa)
        success: function(res){ console.log('success', res); },
        error: function(res){ console.log('error', res); }
    })
})();
```

Minha dúvida é o seguinte: como eu posso "configurar" o EntityFramework para que ele sempre receba uma classe e, se o atributo estiver nulo ele não fazer a atualização do mesmo na base de dados? Existe alguma forma de configurar isso?

> **Nota:** a intenção disso é reduzir a carga do trafego de dados entre o frontend e o backend, assim eu poderia economizar recursos nos dois lados.

Comment: Precisa ser uma solução usando apenas o EF?

Comment: meu trabalho é sobre o front-end e sou obrigado a integrar a biblioteca do back-end (a solução tem módulos desktop e web)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LeandroLuk, recomendo que para melhorar a integridade do seu código utilize algumas práticas:

1 - Definir coluna do banco como 'not null';

2 - Utilizar o annotation '[Required]' nos atributos de sua classe;
Exemplo:

```
internal class Pessoa 
{
    [Required]
    public string primeiroNome { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string segundoNome { get; set; }
    public int idade { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string cpf { get; set; }
    // ... mais outros inúmeros campos
}
```

3 - No seu controller, ao receber o objeto do tipo 'Pessoa', valide se o estado dele é válido da seguinte forma:

```
internal class PessoaController 
{
    private DbContext db;

    [HttpPut("/")]
    internal IActionResult Update([FromBody] Pessoa pessoa)
    {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
          //aqui você escreve o código para atualizar
          //Exemplo: 
          db.Pessoas.Update(pessoa);
          db.SaveChanges();

          return Ok();
       }
       else
       {
          return BadRequest(ex.Message);
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: A minha idéia é exatamente o contrário, é eu não precisar criar multiplas classes que são a mesma coisa, ex `Pessoa { login, senha }` (seria para usuario ou `Pessoa {nome, sobrenome, id}` (seria para listagem simples) ou `Pessoa { ...todos os campos... }` seria para listagem detalhada. O que eu quero fazer é algo como as interfaces que existem no Typescript, que tem campos "opcionais".

Comment: Então, mas de acordo com as boas práticas de arquitetura de software, você não pode sair muito desse caminho. 
Sugiro que para cada entidade, você tenha um DTO (Data Transfer Object) com exatamente os dados mínimos que você precisa. Não vai precisar criar MÚLTIPLAS. Apenas 2. Para cada Entidade de Domínio e um DTO.

Exemplo:

Entidade de Domínio - Pessoa com todos os atributos;
DTO - Pessoa com apenas os atributos que você deseja retornar/transferir entre uma camada e outra;

Citei o modelo de domínios (DDD), mas também você pode se basear no modelo MVVM (Model-View/View-Model).

Comment: entendo. então infelizmente não existe uma forma de simplificar estruturas com c#... creio então que terei que alterar o `[FromBody]` padrão do aspnetcore para que ele aceite receber objetos genéricos (que por padrão vem bloqueado) e a partir de então fazer os tratamentos necessários...